# How to call function after clicking on div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a web app (game) in HTML, CSS and Javascript with jquery and a custom library (mainly for game mechanics).

To keep the game running in the one window I have hidden the different "pages" in divs with the following CSS.

```
.page {
    display:none;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.show {
    z-index: 0 !important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

The relevant game code at the moment is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


//Document ready function
$(document).ready(function() {

//Javascript to change pages. Idea is that when menuButton2 is pushed, page1 is replaced by page2 div
$("#menuButton2").onTap(function() {
  $(".page").removeClass("show");
  $("#page2").addClass("show");
    });



//When menuButton1 is pressed, page3 becomes the displayed div
$("#menuButton1").onTap(function startGame() {
  $(".page").removeClass("show");
  $("#page3").addClass("show");
    });

//Spawns flag images
$("body").append("<div id='italy' style='top: 100px'></div>");
$("#italy").moveTo(90);
$("#italy").speed(0.4);
$("#italy").autoBounceOff(true);
$("#italy").onCollision(function(otherObject) {
  if(otherObject.hasClass("football")) {
  $(this).remove();
  }
});

//When the screen is tapped, shoot function is called and event is logged.     Variable footballNumber also declared.
var footballNumber = 1;
$("body").onTap(function(shoot) {
      console.log(shoot);

//Football image is created and appended to body. It is shot up the screen from the x coordinate of the tap and number of balls is logged to console
  $("body").append("<div id='football" + footballNumber + "' class='football'></div>");
  $("#football" + footballNumber).moveTo(0);
  $("#football" + footballNumber).speed(0.3);
  $("#football" + footballNumber).css("bottom","0px");
  $("#football" + footballNumber).css("left", shoot.clientX + "px");
    console.log("Football: " + footballNumber);
    footballNumber++;
    })
  });

</script>
```

The idea is that when #menuButton1 is pressed, the #page3 div is shown at the front (by z-indexing) and THEN I want the images to spawn/shooting controls to happen and the game to play. I have attached the function startGame to the button tap but haven't called it...i've tried doing this but to no avail successfully.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: You can define CSS class, eg `active_game_div` which has got styling to show div on a page `display:block;` then on your button click `addClass()` for the div you need. eg, `$('.nav-button').click(function(){  var id = $(this).attr('data-target'); $('#'+id).addClass('active_game_div);  });` html for button `<button data-target="page3" class="nav-button">..</button>`